# remove geolocation radius from google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

can anyone help me remove the radius on the geolocation marker? The code im using

```
  var map, GeoMarker;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
    GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
      alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
    });

    GeoMarker.setMap(map);
```

I tried removing         GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'}); but it makes the circle much darker as a  default.

Thanks for any help. (this is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation-marker plugin for geolocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want circle visible, set it's opacity to 0 (and strokeWeight as well)

```
GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 0
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0us1erLh/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the circle, you should instead be using a `google.maps.Marker` instead. [here is the link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) to the Google Maps Javascript API's relevant section on how to do so.